# How to receive data from RS-422 or RS-232 device in linux

Tags: communication, usb-device, hardware

I'm very new in this linux device driver and communication things. If i have to connect this kind of [devices](http://www.aselsan.com.tr/en-us/capabilities/electro-optic-systems/laser-systems-applications/gzm-01-eye-safe-laser-range-finder) with a computer, and receive the data, than how should i start it? should i create a device driver for this device? i am running xenomai patched linux in my system with some rootics framework like orocos and ros, and i would like to interface this range finder with my pc , which i will implement in seperate microcontroller or mini pc latter. But question is where should i start? i know little that i should make a linux device driver for it , but how should and where should i start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Linux machine would need to have one or more UARTs. To access the device your Linux should have device drivers which appear in /dev/[serialdevice].

An alternative is to use a USB to serial converter and see if your Linux has device drivers for that. A great advantage of those is that you can have many serial ports by using USB HUB.

Connecting one or more UARTs and writing device drivers is a non-trivial exercise which goes beyond the help we can give you here. We maybe able to  help you if you get stuck and have specific questions.